# "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I'm trying to create a project in React and I'm using Firebase. In my react-redux-firebase project one line of code making error but I couldn't fix that. How could I fix this "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

I have searched for this problem but couldn't fix the problem.

I'm following a tutorial where the react version is 16.4.1. I'm not sure this is the problem or not

### index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import fbConfig from "./config/fbConfig";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
  )
);
```

> if I comment out the reatReduxFirebase() then it works fine but I need this to work
>
> You could find all codes here: https://github.com/martuza-shimul/React-Blog-app

### I'm getting this error every time:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Module../src/index.js
i:/Learning new things/react/pma/src/index.js:17
  14 | const store = createStore(
  15 |   rootReducer,
  16 |   compose(
> 17 |     applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
  18 |     reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
  19 |     reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
  20 |
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. A little bit of help/hint really be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please use this npm packages
npm packages compatibility issue

```
npm i --save react-redux@5.1.1 react-redux-firebase@2.2.4
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for helping me out @Jay

Comment: Ma dooooood you the best

Answer (score 5):

This is a react-redux-firebase v2.x.x coding pattern and you probably have v3.x.x installed.

1. Check which version of react-redux-firebase you are using:

```
    npm ls react-redux-firebase
```

2. If the version is 3.0.0 or higher, you need to migrate your code to the new coding pattern. See [React-Redux-Firebase v3.x.x Migration Guide](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The reactReduxFirebase store enhancer is removed in the version v3 and above. You can now create firebase instance using context providers. The same can now be done as:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
   applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
   reduxFirestore(fbConfig)
 )
);

const rrfProps = {
firebase,
config: fbConfig,
dispatch: store.dispatch
}

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <Todo />      // your Component
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
 );
```

As of now the 'reduxFirestore' is working fine so I want to leave it as it is but I assume the same will happen to it in coming days. So its a good idea to omit compose and reduxFirestore(fbConfig) and instead use:

```
import { createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore'
```

and add createFirestoreInstance to rrfProps as below:

```
const rrfProps = {
firebase,
config: rrfConfig,
dispatch: store.dispatch,
createFirestoreInstance 
}
```

For more information checkout: http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#remove-createFirebaseConnect-and-createFirestoreConnect

Answer (score 0):

> Option 01- adjust npm package versions for `react-redux & react-redux-firebase`

```
npm install react-redux@5.1.1 react-redux-firebase@2.2.4
```

> Option 02- Refer v3 ( http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html )