# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

having a problem initializing the Firestore.
Here is the code:

In store.js

```
    import { combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { reduxFirestore, firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore';

//Reducers

const firebaseConfig = {};

// react-redux-firebase config
  const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
};

//init firebase instance
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
//init firestore
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

//adding reactReduxFirebase enhencer
firebase.firestore(); // <- needed if using firestore

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer,
});

//create initial state
const initialState = {};
    const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
    export default store;
```

In App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <AppNavbar></AppNavbar>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the error log
| //create initial state
40 |
41 | const initialState = {};

> 42 | const store = createStore(
> 43 |   rootReducer,
> 44 |   initialState,
> 45 |   compose(reactReduxFirebase(firebase))

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please share the browser console screenshot. this problem occurs due to duplicate function/Component in the application

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" react-redux-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709826/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-react-redux-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is specifically with calling `reactReduxFirebase` as it is not a function.

I’m not too familiar with the 'react-redux-firebase' package, but it appears that [this function was removed](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/3d4277be12b5970fa0b31bb3d124375abcab64f5/docs/v3-migration-guide.md) from the latest version.

Instead of applying this enhancer to your store, it is now recommended that you wrap your app in a `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider`.